# cakephp dealing with blob images

Tags: sql, cakephp, blob

I am saving images as blob to my db, as I have to send them later on to an app via api call.

Saving works fine, but I can't select the row when the blob field is filled.

For example:

```
$this->Picture->find('list')
```

returns id and the name of the picture.

```
$this->Picture->find('all')
```

doesn't return anything at all!
I can see the right statement in the sql output, but the find does not return any value.
Not even an empty array, the debug($this->Picture->find('all')) is just empty.

When I delete the content of the blob field, the $this->Picture->find('all') returns me the right row with all it's data.

The field in my DB is BLOB.
What goes wrong here? Any ideas?

The statement look like this:

```
SELECT `Picture`.`id`, `Picture`.`picture`, `Picture`.`name`, `Picture`.`type`, `Picture`.`created`, `Picture`.`modified` FROM `app`.`pictures` AS `Picture` WHERE `Picture`.`id` = 13 LIMIT 1
```

If I run it with the phpmyadmin, there is one row found.

[image]

I use this code in my function:

```
public function show_image($pictureId) {
    $this->set('data', $this->Picture->findById($pictureId));
}
```

the show_image.ctp looks like this:

```
$this->autoRender = false;
$this->response->type($data['Picture']['type']);
$this->response->body($data['Picture']['picture']);
```

I try to call the picture in my view like this:

```
$this->Html->image(Router::url(array('controller' => 'mycontroller', 'action' => 'show_image', $mydata['picture_id'])));
```

Comment: "...as I have to send them later on to an app via api call." - IMO this still doesn't seem reason enough to save images as blob.  Instead, send a link for the app to download the image.

Comment: Please supply the MySQL that query is generating.  Then, try running it in on your database, and let us know if there is a specific error.  (this is always step #1 if you think something SHOULD be found, but isn't)

Comment: @Dave, I get a result when do find('list'), just not when find('all'). That is the strange point...

Comment: how large is the image? If you do `find('all', array('fields' => '')` and put all the fields except `picture`, does it work?

Comment: The file shows 762.5KiB in phpmyadmin. When I use fields to select all EXCEPT 'picture' I get the row data.

Comment: do you think you might get a different result when trying with a smaller image?

Comment: with 6.1KiB => no difference, I added some more details in my code above to show, how I am using it.

Comment: show_image/13 shows me in Firefox that it's a broken jpeg and show_image/14 shows me a broken png. I can see that in the window tab name...

Comment: omg: echo $data['Picture']['picture']; just displays me wired signs. That is a good sign, means data is there, debug() just can't show it. I just need to find the correct way how to send the picture data to the browser!!

Comment: Don't store images in the DB at all, it's slow and a waste of resources. The binary data has to be pushed through mysql, php and the webserver.